# How to run a powershell script with an argument in the background within another script

Tags: powershell

I have two powershell scripts lets call them scriptA and scriptB

ScriptA loops through a list of items and goes through some execution. Once it is ready and has the variables needed I want to call scriptB and provide said variables but launch it in the background so that I can move onto the next item in the list.

Currently I call scriptB with the following:

```
Start-Job -FilePath somepath\scriptB.ps1 -ArgumentList $variable
```

When I run this myself via an interactive session everything works as intended. However, when I schedule scriptA as a scheduled task it does not launch scriptB. No errors are provided it just does not seem to execute or maybe it does and something else is preventing it from launching successfully. I can tell the script doesn't start because I have it writing lines into a log file at the begining before anything else just to check if it gets to start.

I have tried Invoke-Command already and get an error:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -FilePath somepath\scriptB.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

If possible I would like to avoid pasting the whole script into a script block.

**EDIT SOLVED**: As a user suggested I used the following in order for the command to work while launching via scheduled task. New command:

```
start-process powershell.exe @("somepath\scriptB.ps1",$variable) -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: There is so little code to your question that it is impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: What else do you need? I just want to try a replacement to that cmdlet within the context of the situation I've highlighted, I don't think you need anything else. But what else do you need i'll see if I can provide it

Comment: ScriptA is probably not waiting for the started job (scriptB) to finish, hence the scheduled task ends and kills the started job. Without seeing what scriptA is hard to tell.

Comment: But if I run a separate process in the background then doesn't it not care if the scriptA is still executing or not? Also I have been trying to debug this script for a long time now and have seen multiple instances were scriptA runs longer than the multiple scriptB instances that are suppose to launch.

I'm pretty confident that the issue is the start-job cmdlet is for some reason not working properly when ran under a non interactive context. If you can suggest another cmdlet that I can use please let me know

Comment: The child process (created by `Start-Job`) dies if the parent process is killed. And, Jobs, ThreadJobs, Runspaces work perfectly fine in Scheduled Tasks / unattended scripts. If they didn't PowerShell would be a useless scripting language.

Comment: I added a sleep for 1 minute after after the start-job command and tested a few times if scriptB actually starts. First line in scriptB is to write "hello" to a file, no line is written to the file it did not start

Comment: `-FilePath` is only valid for some parameter sets of `Invoke-Command` - based on the error your missing a required argument.  See Syntax section of docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#syntax

Comment: Santiago is correct.  When the PowerShell parent process terminates so do it's jobs.  You can make the parent process wait for the job by giving your ScriptB job a name `Start-Job -Name 'ScriptB'` and then adding `Wait-Job -Name 'ScriptB'` to the end of ScriptA

Comment: The other option is to start ScriptB in a new powershell process `Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList "-windowstyle hidden -f ScriptB.ps1 `"my process args`"" -NoNewWindow`

Comment: If you post your actual code (instead of just describing it)--but reduce it to a minimal reproducible example--folks here will be able to provide much more actionable feedback. Creating the minimal reproducible example may even reveal the problem to you as you go. Ideally, script A for this purpose should be reduced to  essentially two lines: call script B and then wait for it to finish and script B should be a single line (to print "hello" for example). If that does not fail, then you will need to add back more until you get the failure.

Comment: @MichaelSorens The main issue is not that it doesnt work, is that it does not work un-interactively. When I run the script logged onto my user everything is fine scriptB starts and even runs after scriptA is done. The problem as I have highlighted comes when I schedule scriptA as a scheduled task for some reason the start-process cmdlet doesnt work at all and never starts scriptB.

I am going to test the suggestions above and will give updates on the results

Comment: Not sure why you are so reluctant to post your code, but you are missing out on a huge benefit: with actual code, I guarantee there will be folks reading this that will immediately take on the challenge of solving your puzzle, rather than theorizing about it. Code samples are truly the best way to get assistance here.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the suggestion but I'm having a hard time understanding the other option you described. Starting with -Filepath and -f is this not pretty much the same thing, also what does "-filepath powershell" do exactly?

Comment: @MisterSmith I read the docs about -filepath and just in case I moved it to c:\temp\scriptB and tried again and still the same error even though in their examples they use something extremely similar. Could you help me out on understanding what argument you think I was missing?

Comment: @MichaelSorens its not that I'm reluctant and not to sound arrogant or know it all or whatever but I don't think it has any baring on the actual issue that I'm facing. I know the code works when I launch it interactively while I'm logged in, I've seen it, I've stepped through every line. The only issue is that specific line under the specific condition it is run as a scheduled task while the user is not logged on. However, how much would you need in order for it to be sufficient because I'm not going to paste the 1000+ lines here

Comment: @user14488986 - my point is `-filepath` must be used with another option. The syntax section of link shows you each way invoke-command may be executed (aka parameter sets) - calling  it interactively one of the other options are probably implied which is why it works. Anyway if your ScriptB is long running you should consider @Daniel's idea of `Start-Process powershell.exe c:\somepath\scriptB.ps1 $arg` - seperate powershell.exe to run ScriptB. You can also create/modify a Scheduled Task ScriptB (using powershell.exe and ScriptB as arg and no triggers) then manually start the task from ScriptA

Comment: @MisterSmith Thanks for the update I tried the following first:
`Start-Process powershell.exe c:\somepath\scriptB.ps1`

This worked and opened a new window great. I then tried to get the -ArgumentList which did not work but also tried it similar to the format you shared:
`Start-Process powershell.exe c:\temp\ScriptB.ps1 $variable`

and got the following error

`Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'testing'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe c:\temp\ScriptB.ps1`

Comment: My bad. ScriptB.ps1 is one of the args to the new powershell.exe instance so try something like `start-process powershell.exe @("c:\temp\ScriptB.ps1","hello", 21, "no")` - where ScriptB starts like this: `Param([String] $SomeArg, [Int] $AnArg, [String] $OtherArg)` to declare the 3 parameters. If you need further help you will need to edit your question and add details of what args your passing to ScriptB.

Comment: @MisterSmith Thank you I think this is solved now i tested on my own and with the scheduled task it seems to be working and even running after scriptA is done. Everything looks like its in order now, thanks again. Any idea why this works and my previous command did not?

Comment: If ScriptA exits just after `Start-Job` that could be killing it. As for `Invoke-Command` its currently complaining about arguments and i cant see the code so i dont know  - but i suspect this will have the same issue as `Start-Job` anyway.

Comment: Did you try the `Wait-Job` suggestion?